# Bist du deppert!

Tags: sentence-structure, semantics

Wer in Österreich lebt, hört im Schnitt mindestens einmal täglich diesen Ausruf:

> Bist du deppert!

<sup>*(Es gibt im österreichischen Privatfernsehen sogar eine wiederkehrende Sendung gleichen Names, in der man die Verschwendung von Steuergeldern anprangert.)*</sup>

Ich habe eine Frage zum Satzbau dieses Aufrufs. Weil mir aber nicht klar ist, wie gut das Wort *»deppert«* auch außerhalb Österreichs bekannt ist, will ich es kurz erläutern. Wer das Wort bereits gut kennt, kann diese Erläuterung gerne überspringen.

- **Zum Wort »deppert«**

  Das Wort »deppert« ist das Adjektiv zum Nomen »Depp« (Dummkopf, Idiot). Es gehört zur österreichischen Umgangssprache, wird auch von Österreichern nicht als Teil der Standardsprache angesehen, und wird wie viele Adjektive in ost-österreichischen Dialekten durch Anfügen der Endsilbe *»-ert«* an ein Nomen oder Verb gebildet.
  <sub>*z.B. Die Luke → lukert = löchrig; stinken → stinkert (ein stinkerter Käse), wackeln → wacklert (ein wacklerter Tisch)*</sub>

  Eine standarddeutsche Übersetzung des gegenständlichen Ausrufs wäre also z.B.

  > Bist du blöd!

  Eine typische Verwendung:

  > *Bernd:* Die Pleite der Hypo-Alpe-Adria-Bank hat jeden einzelnen Österreicher im Schnitt 1800 Euro gekostet!
  >   *Klaus:* **Bist du deppert!**

  Der genannte Ausruf ist zwar eine sehr häufige Verwendung des Adjektivs *deppert*, aber es ist keineswegs nur auf diesen Ausruf beschränkt. Es wird auch außerhalb dieser Fügung wie die meisten anderen Adjektive attributiv (*»Du und dein deppertes Bier«* = Du und dein blödes Bier), prädikativ (*»Mei Bier is ned deppert«* = Mein Bier ist nicht blöd) und adverbial (*»Frog ned so deppert«* = Frag nicht so blöd) verwendet.

**Zur Frage (Satzbau)**

Meine Frage dreht sich aber nicht um das Wort an sich, sondern um die Grammatik des Satzes. Der Satz beginnt ja mit dem Verb, damit entspricht der Satzbau voll und ganz dem einer geschlossenen Frage (also einer Frage, die mit *ja* oder *nein* zu beantworten ist):

> Bist du deppert? – Bist du blöd?

So ist der Ausruf aber nicht gemeint. Semantisch ist dieser Satz keine Frage. Niemand, der diesen Ausruf tätigt, erwartet darauf eine Antwort und niemand, der diesen Ausruf kennt, würde ihn als Frage interpretieren. Es ist ein Ausruf plötzlichen Erstaunens oder sogar ein Ausruf des Entsetzens. Häufig gefolgt von *»Des gibt's jo ned!«* (*»Das gibt es ja nicht!«*) um auszudrücken, dass es einem schwer fällt, den eben gehörten Sachverhalt als wahr anzuerkennen.

Als Ausruf müsste der Satz eigentlich wie eine Aussage gebaut sein, mit dem Verb an Position 2:

> Du bist deppert! – Du bist blöd!

Das geht an der tatsächlich transportierten Bedeutung aber noch weiter vorbei, denn in *»bist du deppert!«* ist mit *du* keine bestimmte Person gemeint, schon gar nicht der Gesprächspartner.

Irgendwie will dieser Satz in kein mir bekanntes grammatisch/semantisches Schema passen. Mir fallen auch keine anderen Fragen ein, die als Ausruf ihren semantischen Fragecharakter vollkommen verlieren.

Gibt es auch noch andere ähnliche Beispiele?
Wenn der Satz semantisch keine Frage ist, wie ist er dann grammatisch zu bewerten?

Comment: Es ist auch in Bayern und darüber hinaus bekannt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IASVKgZ5T8o

Comment: Danke! Es fällt mir immer sehr schwer, das Verbreitungsgebiet eines Ausdrucks einzuschätzen, den ich als typisch österreichisch empfinde. Aber da die meisten in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte bayrische Dialekte sind, wundert es mich nicht, wenn vieles davon auch in Bayern bekannt ist.

Comment: Ich glaube sehr wohl, dass sich der Ausdruck ursprünglich von einer Frage ableitet, und dem Gegenüber galt. Die Situation war so absurd, so schwer fasslich, so ungewöhnlich, dass man quasi die "geistige Gesundheit" des Gesprächspartners hinterfragen musste. Das hat sich im normalen Sprachgebrauch zu einem Ausruf verändert, der auch niemand bestimmtem mehr gilt, aber die Inversion der Frage beibehalten hat.

Comment: @Ingmar: Kannst du das näher ausführen und in eine Antwort packen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich glaube, das irgendwo gelesen zu haben. Komme aber vor Montag nicht an meine Bücher.

Comment: @Ingmar: du kannst ruhig schon mal eine vorläufige Antwort verfassen, die du dann am Montag mit Quellenangaben oder Details noch aufwerten kannst. Fragen und Antworten sollen nicht statisch sein, es ist durchaus erwünscht, wenn hier eine Evolution zum Besseren stattfindet. Wenn du (unbegründet!) Angst vor einem Downvote hast, dann kannst du ja schreiben, dass am Montag noch mehr kommt.

Comment: Es handelt sich um eine rhetorische Frage. Die Antwort "Ja, bist du" ist dem Fragesteller bereits bekannt.

Comment: @scienceponder: Nein. Auch bei einer rhetorischen Frage wird sowohl vom Sender als auch vom Empfänger wahrgenommen, dass es sich um eine Frage handelt. In der Niederschrift setzt man daher auch am Ende einer rhetorischen Frage ein Fragezeichen. *Nicht wahr?* Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall. Weder der Sprecher noch seine Zuhörer nehmen die Phrase *»Bist du deppert!«* als Frage wahr. Sie wird - im Gegensatz zu einer rhetorischen Frage - auch nicht wie eine Frage betont, sondern eben wie ein Ausruf. ...

Comment: ... Und im Gegensatz zu deinem vermutlich scherzhaft gemeinten zweiten Satz wird mit dieser Frage auch nicht versucht, dem Gesprächsparter zu unterstellen *deppert* (also *blöd*) zu sein.

Comment: Anderes Beispiel, dass dem gleichen Aufbau folgt und genauso bekannt sein sollte: "Ist es denn die Möglichkeit!" gerne mit einem "Ja" noch vorangestellt. Alternativ denglisch verballhornt "Ist es denn die possibility/possibilität"

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu den anderen Beispielen ("wacklert"), die hier niemand verstehen würde, ist "deppert" auch in Berlin bekannt, allerdings würde man es hier definitiv als Frage und somit mehr oder weniger ernste Beleidigung auffassen. Die Benutzung im Sinne von "Na sowas!" ist hierzulande praktisch unbekannt.

Comment: Der Ausruf erscheint mir syntaktisch ähnlich gebaut wie "Hast du Töne!"; wie das betont wird, weiß ich nicht. Semantisch erscheint er mir vergleichbar mit "Wie isses nun zu fassen!" von Kempowskis Mutter (Hamburger Herkunft, die Familie lebte in Rostock). Für diese Art von ungläubigem Erstaunen gibt es eine Unmasse von Sprüchen (ich glaub' ich steh' im Wald… - die grüne Neune, der Scholli und der Herr Gesangverein und aus der heiligen Ecke das Blechle, der Strohsack und der Bimbam lassen grüßen), sie alle und noch viel mehr mit ihren eigenen Nuancen.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia schreibt im Artikel über die [V1-Stellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung) (Verb-Erst-Stellung) :

> Zum anderen kommen Ausrufe in verschiedenen Funktionen als V1-Sätze vor, vor allem Aufforderungen (Imperative), Wünsche (Optativ) und Ausrufe der Verwunderung.

Beispiel:

[Och Kinder, ist das hier gemütlich bei uns!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgB90OsLAJY&t=335)

Comment: Ich habe gerade den Wikipedia-Artikel über die V1-Stellung gelesen. Kannst du bitte deine Antwort noch ein wenig ausführlicher gestalten (vor allem in Bezug auf Ausrufesätze)? Denn dann würde ich sie nämlich als beste Antwort akzeptieren.

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin zwar keiner, kann mir aber vorstellen, dass ein Deutscher von nördlich der Mainlinie den Ausdruck

> bist du deppert

möglicherweise mit einem fragenden Blick oder sogar beleidigt aufnehmen könnte, obwohl er, wie du richtig geschrieben hast, gar nicht so gemeint ist.

Im oberdeutschen Sprachraum sollte der Ausdruck einigermaßen bekannt sein, in Bayern als Mitglied der gleichen Sprachfamilie sowieso. Ich würde (Südwestdeutschland) den Ausdruck nicht verwenden, aber verstehen.

Solche, in eine Frageform gepackten Ausdrücke, die durch die (offensichtliche) Unerhörtheit des Kontextes klar nicht als Frage gemeint sind, gibt es auch in anderen Sprachregionen. So habe ich zum Beispiel schon

> Ja spinn' ich denn?

(worauf der Frager sicher keine bestätigende Antwort möchte) oder

> Ja spinnt der denn?

In Berlin hörte ich auch schon

> Watt isn dit für'n Fatzke?

Was sicher auch nicht als Frage gemeint war.

Comment: Wenn du den Ausruf schriftlich am Ende mit einem Fragezeichen versiehst, entsteht der falsche Eindruck, dieser Ausruf würde auch in der gesprochenen Sprache wie eine Frage ausgesprochen (Hebung der Stimme bei der letzten Silbe). Das ist aber nicht der Fall. Tatsächlich wird die erste Silbe (*Bist*) extrem stark betont und oft auch langgezogen, in jeder nachfolgenden Silbe sinkt die Tonhöhe leicht ab. Das Fragezeichen ist in der schriftlichen Wiedergabe daher keinesfalls angemessen.

Comment: Bin kein Deutscher, lebe aber schon seit 1985 nördlich der Main-Linie. Der Ausdruck ist mir geläufig und ich vermute, dass die meisten hier das auch verstehen, aber nicht selber sagen würden.

Answer (score 1):

Die Nuancen zur Bedeutung von *[deppert](https://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/Bist_du_deppert)* mögen sich sehr unterscheiden, je weiter man über den Main nach Norden gelangt. Aber dennoch:
Beispiele, die so ähnlich funktionieren:

–– Du kriegst die Tür nicht zu!
Klingt wie eine direkte Ansprache, ist aber ebenfalls nur ein Ausruf des Erstaunens.

–– Scheiß die Wand an!
Kling erstmal wie ein Befehl, läßt gar da "Du" aus, ist aber ebenfall nicht direkt an irgendwelche Gegenüber gerichtet.

–– [Leck mich fett! (Ausruf des Erstaunens)](https://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-7727-Bist_deppert-Bist_du_blod.html)

Die genannten Beispiele lassen sich unterschiedlich gut natürlich auch als Frage betonen.

Comment: Befehle, die nicht in der Höflichkeitsform formuliert sind (»Scheißen Sie die Wand an!«) enthalten niemals ein Personalpronomen. (Nicht »Komm du her!«, sondern »Komm her!«) Das fehlende »du« ist die Regel, nicht die Ausnahme.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist nicht so einfach, wie mir scheint. Die von Ihnen in den Kommentaren verworfene Vermutung, dass es sich um eine rhetorische Frage handelt, würde ich nicht so schnell von der Hand weisen. Zugleich lassen sich aber Eigenschaften beobachten, die eher einen (Verb-Erst-)Exklamativsatz vermuten lassen.

Zunächst zu letzterem: Der V1-Satz ist eine der möglichen, relativ seltenen Konfigurationen des Exklamativmodus ([Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1876)). Ihre Bemerkung zur Satzmelodie (in einem Kommentar zu einer anderen Antwort), wonach "die erste Silbe (Bist) extrem stark betont und oft auch langgezogen" werde und "in jeder nachfolgenden Silbe [...] die Tonhöhe leicht absinkt", ist vor diesem Hintergrund recht interessant, denn eine derartige terminale Intonationskontur nach dem Exklamativakzent ist für diesen Satztypus gerade auch charakteristisch *(Hast DU eine Ahnung! ↓; Stellst DU dich an! ↓)*. Überhaupt ist das Bestehen eines gedehnten Exklamativakzents ebenfalls ein Wesensmerkmal von V1-Exklamativsätzen. Der Exklamativakzent kann hierbei auch auf dem finiten Verb liegen (*SCHREIT der wieder rum!*). Was hier im Beispiel derweil fehlt, ist die typische (Altmann 1993) Austauschbarkeit mit dem V2-Typ, ggf. unter Partikelergänzung. Vgl. etwa *Hast du eine Ahnung! / Du hast [vielleicht] eine Ahnung!* Bei einer solchen Modifikation würde hier wohl die Bedeutung verschoben. (Ich komme noch darauf zurück.)

Auf semantischer Ebene fällt auf, dass sich die Aussage nicht, auch nicht rhetorisch, an ein Mitglied der Hörergruppe richtet. Bekanntlich kann *du* aber auch im inneren Monolog verwendet werden oder unpersönlich verweisend (*man*-Äquivalent; vgl. etwa: *Jede Hausfrau weiß: Wenn die Tiefkühltruhe vereist ist, hast du keine andere Möglichkeit als abzutauen.*). Eine solche Verwendung erscheint hier naheliegend. Die an den Sprecher selbst gerichtete Frage, ob er denn deppert sei, lässt sich dann aber m.E. schon auch dem Wesen nach als rhetorische Frage klassifizieren.

Zu bedenken ist bei alledem (sowohl den Ausführungen zur V1-Exklamative als auch denen zur rhetorischen Frage), dass wir es hier offenkundig mit weit fortgeschrittener Idiomatisierung zu tun haben. Dies kann auch geeignet sein, Abweichungen vom Üblichen zu erklären (wie etwa die fehlende V1-V2-Austauschbarkeit, vielleicht aber eben auch, wenn man von einer rhetorischen Frage ausgeht, die in der Tat ungewöhnliche Betonung). Vielleicht liegt die Wahrheit auch einfach irgendwo dazwischen.